# How to add a new foreign key property to existing data in EF core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

How do you add a new foreign key property to existing data in EF Core?

Say you have some models, you create a new model which will have a foreign key to one of your existing models.

add-migration will fail because the existing records won't have the foreign key.  What is the right approach to solving this?

Answer (score 1):

I was in this situation before and I found 2 possible scenarios.

**Scenario one.**

If you plan to update the existing data after the changes apply than you can do this in a couple steps:

1. Create the initial FK and configure it as `nullable`.
2. Do the migration.
3. Update the existing rows with a value for the FK.
4. Reconfigure the property and set it as required.
5. Do the final migration.

**Scenario two.** (This one I like more)

You can add in the new table the value as "N/A" for example and than update all the existing rows during the migration with this value.

1. Configure the new model and make sure you add also some initial data using `.HasData()` extension.
2. Run the migration.
3. Add and configure the property in the existing model with a default value. Example ID = 1 would be for "N/A" in the new table.
4. Run the second migration.

I'm not entirely sure that this would qualify as a "best practice" but it did the trick for every single time.